# Javascript - String split

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have the following string

```
str = "11122+3434"
```

I want to split it into ["11122", "+", "3434"]. There can be following delimiters +, -, /, *

I have tried the following

```
strArr = str.split(/[+,-,*,/]/g)
```

But I get

```
strArr = [11122, 3434]
```

Comment: there can be different delimiters or there can be one at a time

Comment: you want to split only mathematical expressions or anything else?

Comment: only one delimiter at a time. I want to split only mathematical expressions

Comment: keep it simple, `str.split(/([-+*/])/)`

Answer (score 4):

Delimiters are things that separate **data**. So the `.split()` method is designed to remove delimiters since delimiters are not data so they are not important at all.

In your case, the thing between two values is also data. So it's not a delimiter, it's an operator (in fact, that's what it's called in mathematics).

For this you want to parse the data instead of splitting the data. The best thing for that is therefore regexp:

```
var result = str.match(/(\d+)([+,-,*,/])(\d+)/);
```

returns an array:

```
["11122+3434", "11122", "+", "3434"]
```

So your values would be `result[1]`, `result[2]` and `result[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

This should help...

```js
str = '11122+3434+12323*56767'
strArr = str.replace(/[+,-,*,/]/g, ' $& ').split(/ /g)
console.log(strArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, one way is to add a space as delimiter first.

```
// yes,it will be better to use regex for this too
str = str.replace("+", " + ");
```

Then split em

```
strArr = str.split(" ");
```

and it will return your array

```
["11122", "+", "3434"]
```

Answer (score 1):

in bracket +-* need escape, so

```
strArr = str.split(/[\+\-\*/]/g)
```

Comment: this won't give you the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "11122+77-3434";

function getExpression(str) {
  var temp = str.split('');
  var part = '';
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    if (temp[i].match(/\d/) && part.match(/\d/g)) {
      part += temp[i];
    } else {
      result.push(part);
      part = temp[i]
    }
    if (i === temp.length - 1) { //last item
      result.push(part);
      part = '';
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(getExpression(str))
```